# Can i Use an intent Like this way in Android Activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

my activities overflow diagram is as follows :

Main_Activity  ---> Detail_Activity  ---> Expandablelist_Activity
using intent always done via this bock of code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,DetailActivity.class)
                    .putExtra("movieInfo",feedItem);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

But, i want to set my intent to start in Expandablelist_Activity which will be reached via the Detail_Activity, and `.putExtra("movieInfo",feedItem);`  is in the Main_Activity, so i want to set this intent block of code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,DetailActivity.class)
                    .putExtra("movieInfo",feedItem);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
Intent intent_reviews = new Intent(mContext,Expandablelist.class)
        .putExtra("movieInfo",feedItem);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

without using `mContext.startActivity(Expandablelist_Activity.class);` method, just only to enable passing the required data object to the Expandablelist Activity when it used later after displaying the Detail_Activity.

Can  anybody tell me if this step is true, and if false, how can i get the intent in a later activity without starting it. in advance of all, your response will be appreciated.

Comment: You can always call `getIntent()` in the next Activity. I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: In any case, remove `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`. You definitely do NOT need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have `MainActivity`, `DetailActivity`, `ExpandableActivity`. From your question looks like you trying to do following:

- from `MainActivity` start `DetailActivity` and path `movieInfo` as intent payload.
- then from `DetailActivity` start `ExpandableActivity` with same payload.

If I've correctly understood your question you need to do the following:

In `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,DetailActivity.class)
                .putExtra("movieInfo",feedItem);
startActivity(intent);
```

In `DetailActivity`:

```
//When you want to open ExpandableActivity with same payload
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent != null) {
   intent.setClass(this, ExpandableActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

In `ExpandableActivity`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent != null) {
   //Use extra
}
```

Comment: Wow , it's the best benefit, Thank you